# Looking for the right RE expression (python)

Tags: python, regex

I want to make a python script, that look for:

```
    <span class="toujours_cacher">(.)*?</span>
```

I use this RE:

```
    r"(?i)\<span (\n|\t| )*?class=\"toujours_cacher\"(.|\n)*?\>(.|\n)*?\<\/span\>"
```

However, in some of my pages, I found this kind of expression

```
    <span class="toujours_cacher">*
    <span class="exposant" size="1">*</span> *</span>
```

so I tried this RE:

```
    r"(?i)\<span (\n|\t| )*?class=\"toujours_cacher\"(.|\n)*?\>(.|\n)*?(\<\/span\>|\<\/span\>(.|\n)*?<\/span>)"
```

which is not good, because when there is no span in between, it looks for the next .

I need to delete the content between the span with the class "toujours_cacher".
Is there any way to do it with one RE?

I will be pleased to hear any of your suggestions :)

Comment: If you're parsing HTML or XML, please don't try to use regex. Take a look at ETree, BeautifulSoup, or some other parsing library.

Comment: This does not do what you think it does: `(.|\n)*` .  You need to learn about character classes, and where to put the parenthesis around capture groups.

Comment: I can only use 'standart' python for this, it is a script for people who don't know anything about programming and who won't be able to install modules

Comment: @whitefret Well then teach them to parse a `regular` text file or something using regular expressions. Not a webpage, because you are teaching them to use regex incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

This is (provably) impossible with regular expressions - they cannot match delimiters to arbitrary depth.  You'll need to move to using an actual parser instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use regex to parse HTML, as it is not regular. You could use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Here is an example of BeautifulSoup finding the tag `<span class="toujours_cacher">(.)*?</span>`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlCode)
spanTags = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'toujours_cacher'})
```

This will return a list of all the `span` tags that have the class `toujours_cacher`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I guess I will have to make a note for BeautifulSoup's install